# Is strict inclusion meant or not in: " If B is a subset of a WO set A, any element of A under a similarity mapping from A to B precedes its image"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I use Lipschutz's *Theory and problems of set theory*.

In Solved problem n°4 of ch 11, it is asked to prove Theorem 11.7, that is : if A and B are similar well ordered sets, there exists only one similarity mapping of A into B."

In the solution given, Lipzchutz uses another theorem ( TH 11.6 ) according to which : If A is well ordered and B is a subset of A, and if f is a similarity mapping from A to B, then  a precedes ( or is eual to)  f(a) ( for all a belonging to A).

The reason he uses this theorem 11.6 is that he defines by function composition a mapping ( inverse of g ° f) for which the image would strictly precede the preimage, which would contradict TH 11.6, since this composed mapping is from A to A.

My question : does TH 11.6 apply when B , defined as subset of A , is also equal to A ( as Lipschutz seems to imply).  Does this theorem also hold in case of non-strict inclusion?

In case it held, we wouldn't we have this version of TH 11.6

" For all similarity mapping *f* from A to A itself, and for all element *a* belonging to A : a precedes ( or is equal to) f(a) " .

Comment: How does that alleged theorem hold when $A=\omega$ and $B$ is the **proper** subset $\{x\in\omega:x\text{ is even}\}$ and $f(n)=2n$? Are you sure you aren't misquoting it?

Comment: @bof.  If 0 is excluded, does not x strictly precede f(x) in the relation " < " ? The example you give is the one given by the author to introduce the theorem.

Comment: You said that $a\lt f(a)$ for **all** $a\in A$ , didn't you? So in particular you're saying that $0\lt f(0)$. Or define $B=\omega\setminus\{1000\}$ and define $f(n)=n$ for all $n\lt1000$ and $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\ge1000$. Maybe there's a typo in your book, and $a\lt f(a)$ was supposed to read $a\le f(a)$?

Comment: @bof. I've edited my post. Thanks for correcting my mistake. Do you have any comment on the "strict/ non strict" inclusion part of the question. II wanted to make sure that , in the theorem I refer to, " subset" could be read as non proper subset.